# What is difference between xmlns:i and xmlns:xsi attributes in XML format? And how to query for xmlns:i value in SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml

Below is my XML column data sample in SQL Table column of XML type.

```
<MyRootNode xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="i1">
  <MyValue>This is sample text</MyValue>
</MyRootNode>
```

I try retrieve the xml node value as follows;

```
SELECT MY_XML_COLUMN.value('(/MyRootNode/MyValue)[1]', 'varchar') FROM MY_TABLE
```

The above returns NULL. However, if the XML is stored in table with `xmlns:xsi`, it is correctly returning the value.

The xml column is being saved using `xml.runtime.serialization`, it is storing this way. Any help appreciated on querying this from SQL side rather than attempt to fix the saving part from the program which is costly. Thanks

Comment: The `i` local name doesn't appear to be used in the XML at all. Are you sure your sample is representative of the problematic XML?

Comment: For instance, if I put the XML shown into a table and then run your query, I get `T`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, exactly the same representation of problematic XML. Do you think it's an organization specific XML implementation?

Comment: The `i` and `xsi` in `xmlns:i` and `xmlns:xsi` have no meaning by themselves, except to associate elements and attributes to a particular namespace. The important thing is what the `i` and `xsi` reference, that being the namespace. In your example XML the `i` and `z` could be replaced with `foo` and `bar` and the data would still be accessible. The issue with your query is that you haven't specified a data length for `varchar` so it defaults to a length of 1. Try using at least `varchar(19)` and you'll get `This is sample text` as your result.